# not able to update adapter's button in a linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have to implement the following view:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/default_button_height"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_alpha_button"
                android:textColor="@color/labels"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_font_size"
                android:text="@string/no_ora_inizio"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/listTargets"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

In the linearLayout listTargest I want to add a set of adapter, every adapters are defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/alpha_white" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/counterContainer"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/labels"
        android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/counterContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSub"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_alpha_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_big_font_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_font_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_alpha_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/labels"
            android:textSize="@dimen/label_big_font_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the UI is not working property because when I tap on the buttons in the adapter the UI is not updated

Can you help me? Any Idea?

Regards

Comment: Adapter for what? A listview?

Comment: yes, orginally was a listview but is not correct to put a listview in a scrollview

Comment: Post your Java source.